# Finding Max Question

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array, foreach, max

I have such a list `List<Double[,]>`. Let's call each 2-dimensional array in the list a layer. So I should compare each element in each layer and extract max. And construct layer of max values.

How do I do that? Maybe with use of LINQ? Or foreach loop construction?

Help!

And Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify a little further? How do you want the elements in each "layer" to be compared? Do you want to max among all of them (per-layer)? How would the result map to a layer? Wouldn't it be a `List<Double>`?

Comment: If might be worth it going for `double[][]` instead of `double[,]` because then you can use all the statements that work only with 1D arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all your layers are the same size `sizeX`x`sizeY`, because otherwise this makes no sense:

```
var maxLayer = new Double[sizeX,sizeY];

for( int x = 0; x <= maxLayer.GetUpperBound(0); x++ )
    for( int y = 0; y <= maxLayer.GetUpperBound(1); y++ )
        maxLayer[x,y] = Double.NegativeInfinity;

foreach( Double[,] layer in list )
    for( int x = 0; x <= maxLayer.GetUpperBound(0); x++ )
        for( int y = 0; y <= maxLayer.GetUpperBound(1); y++ )
            maxLayer[x,y] = Math.Max( maxLayer[x,y], layer[x,y] );
```

Nothing clever here.

Answer (score 6):

```
var x = new double[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
var y = new double[,] { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
var list = new List<double[,]> { x, y };

var maxValues = list
    .Select(arg => arg.Cast<double>().Max())
    .ToList();
```

So as I understand x and y are levels.
The the result will be 4 and 8, which are max on level x and y respectively.

**[Edit]**

Seems like I misunderstood the question.
To find the level with max you can use code like this:

```
var maxLevel = list
    .Select(arg => new { Max = arg.Cast<double>().Max(), Level = arg })
    .OrderByDescending(arg => arg.Max)
    .Select(arg => arg.Level)
    .First();
```

Comment: No, I need `new Double[,]` which will contain `{{5,6}{7,8}}`

Comment: @helicera - did you try the second query from my answer? Was it something you were looking for?